# Rpi4B and Midas 10" 1280 x 800 HDMI Monitor Interface Problem

Tags: linux, display

I have a raspberry pi 4 using the latest Os but I cant get anything to display on my monitor the monitor I am using is MCT101HDMI-A I have tried another monitor and it display works so I know nothing wrong with the Pi or the SD card as i can also SSH into it.

My config.txt setting are currently:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87

hdmi_cvt=1280 800 60 5 0 0 0

#hdmi_timings=1280 0 16 44 100 800 0 10 3 10 0 0 0 60 0 71000000 7

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=7

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99772/discussion-on-question-by-fxudarknova-raspberry-pi-4-hdmi-screen-is-blank).

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> How can Rpi4B talk to Midas 10" I2C CTP/RTP TFT HDMI monitor MCT101HDMI-A?

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Answer***

It appears that you need to connect three cables from Rpi to HDMI monitor, not just one HDMI cable, as for ordinary HDMI monitors.  I guess this is because you monitor has a touch screen, so is actually a HAT, with 40 pins connected to Rpi.

[image: hdmi mon connect]

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [Midas 10" I2C CTP/RTP TFT HDMI monitor MCT101HDMI-A User Guide](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2622303.pdf)

(2) [4 Easy Steps To Raspberry Pi Connection - Midas Displays 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jDRPCYfqhw)

*/ to continue, ...*

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix - Rpi4B Bootloader*

[Checking/Updating the bootloader (sudo apt install rpi-eeprom)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md)

> We recommend setting up your Pi so that it automatically updates the
>   bootloader: this means you will get new features and bug fixes as they
>   are released. Bootloader updates are performed by the rpi-eeprom
>   package, which installs a service that runs at boot-time to check for
>   critical updates.

Appendix B - [Rpi config.txt readme](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/README.md)

*The Raspberry Pi uses a configuration file instead of the BIOS you would expect to find on a conventional PC. The system configuration parameters, which would traditionally be edited and stored using a BIOS, are stored instead in an optional text file named config.txt. This is read by the GPU before the ARM CPU and Linux are initialised.*

*It must therefore be located on the first (boot) partition of your SD card, alongside bootcode.bin and start.elf. This file is normally accessible as /boot/config.txt from Linux, and must be edited as root. From Windows or OS X it is visible as a file in the only accessible part of the card. If you need to apply some of the config settings below, but you don't have a config.txt on your boot partition yet, simply create it as a new text file.*

*Any changes will only take effect after you have rebooted your Raspberry Pi. After Linux has booted, you can view the current active settings using the following commands:*

> vcgencmd get_config : this displays a specific config value,
>   e.g. vcgencmd get_config arm_freq.
>
> vcgencmd get_config int: this lists all the integer config options
>   that are set (non-zero).
>
> vcgencmd get_config str: this lists all the string config options that
>   are set (non-null).

Note that there are a few config settings that cannot be retrieved using vcgencmd.

*File format
The config.txt file is read by the early-stage boot firmware, so it has a very simple file format. The format is a single property=value statement on each line, where value is either an integer or a string. Comments may be added, or existing config values may be commented out and disabled, by starting a line with the ... character.*

Here is an example file:

> Force the monitor to HDMI mode so that sound will be sent over HDMI cable hdmi_drive=2
>
> Set monitor mode to DMT hdmi_group=2
>
> Set monitor resolution to 1024x768 XGA 60Hz (HDMI_DMT_XGA_60) hdmi_mode=16
>
> Make display smaller to stop text spilling off the screen
>
> overscan_left=20 overscan_right=12 overscan_top=10 overscan_bottom=10
>   config.txt Options

*A range of options can be specified using the config.txt file. These are split into different sections, indexed below:*

> Memory
>
> Licence Keys
>
> Codecs Video
>
> ***Display***
>
> Audio
>
> Camera
>
> Boot
>
> Ports
>
> Device Tree
>
> GPIOs
>
> Overclocking
>
> Conditional Filters
>
> Miscellaneous

---

*/ to continue, ...*

---