# How do I use extended pins with the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gpio

Might be biting off more than I can chew with this project but I received a raspberry pi + touch screen kit and wanted to add 2 max31865 chips. Screen takes up most pins but luckily has ' extended the 13*2 Pin Socket signal Pin-to-Pin '

- Does this mean I can reuse pin-outs ?
- Do they keep the same address and I just pretend like there is no screen attached?

The manual came with a pin map and labeled a bunch as 'no connected' are those the only ones free to use, cant be used, or use any its just a description?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMm9f.jpg :1 Photo of Pi+extended pins, 1 Photo of screen pin map

I am very confused on how the Pi will interact with these, hoping for some guidance before I try to solder on wires and wreak it all

Comment: Hi @Sean Long, Welcome and nice to meet you. Ah, let me see. You LCD monitor seems  SPI controlled. That means only the SPI pins are used by the LCD. I guess you can used all the pins labelled N.C. You can find more references in my answer to the following question:
Rpi4B and Midas 10" 1280 x 800 HDMI Monitor Interface Problem
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104430/raspberry-pi-4-hdmi-screen-is-blank. Good luck and cheers.

Comment: And actually you can use more than the NC pins labelled in your photo. The Rpi to LCD monitor connector is only 26 pins. In other words, for the Rpi with 40 pins. You can use ALL the 40 - 26 = 14 pins.  Warning: I am just guessing.  There is no guarantee that something won't melt down or blow up! :)

Comment: To make it simple a access the GPIO pins, you may consider using stackableHATs： “How to tap/tee/fork the Rpi GPIO pins covered/blocked by a HAT/pHAT/bonnet?”
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/how-to-tap-tee-fork-the-rpi-gpio-pins-covered-blocked-by-a-hat-phat-bo

Comment: What model Pi are you using?

Comment: The Pi is a version 3 model B. With confidence gained thanks to tlfong01, I'll try to solder a connector/hat onto the back of the LCD and hope things just work.. If I do unfortunately melt it at least I'll be the wiser since I've already learned some stuff and its not broke yet!